# Porque ocorre conflito de dias na API do Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação. E nela estou utilizando a API do Carbon. Porém está acontecendo conflitos de dias de um mês a outro. Hoje estamos em 31 de Julho. E o codigo que utilizei foi o seguinte:

```
    $inicioMesAtual = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
    $fimMesAtual =  Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();

    $inicioMesPassado = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth();
    $fimMesPassado = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

Aconteceu que no `$fimMesAtual` dá o mesmo resultado que o `$fimMesPassado`

As saidas ficaram assim:

```
Carbon @1564628399 {#350 ▼
  date: 2019-07-31 23:59:59.999999 America/Sao_Paulo (-03:00)
}
Carbon @1564628399 {#352 ▼
  date: 2019-07-31 23:59:59.999999 America/Sao_Paulo (-03:00)
}
```

Esse caso ocorre também para o início do mês (O inicio desse mês é o mesmo do inicio do mês passado). Alguém poderia me explicar o porque disso estar acontecendo? Antes de 31 de Julho o inicio e fim do mês passado funcionavam bem. Porquê só agora em 31 de Julho não está funcionando? Como posso concertar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) do Carbon alerta sobre isso:

> By default, Carbon relies on the underlying parent class PHP DateTime
>   behavior. As a result adding or subtracting months can overflow.

Caso esteja utilizando a versão 2 do Carbon, você pode resolver o problema de duas formas.

Desabilitar o comportamento de estouro através do método `settings` para cada instância:

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$dt->settings([
    'monthOverflow' => false
]);

$inicioMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonth()->startOfMonth();
$fimMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

Ou utilizar os próprios métodos que previnem esse estouro:

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$inicioMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonthsNoOverflow()->startOfMonth();
$fimMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonthsNoOverflow()->endOfMonth();
```

---

Se estiver usando a versão 1 do Carbon, pode utilizar `Carbon::useMonthsOverflow(false)`.

```
Carbon::useMonthsOverflow(false);
$dt = Carbon::now();
$inicioMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonth()->startOfMonth();
$fimMesPassado = $dt->copy()->subMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

> Note que nos exemplos utilizei o método `copy()` para gerar uma cópia
>   do objeto Carbon para que este não seja alterado conforme as
>   interações que são feitas.

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, parece que estou utilizando a versão 1 do carbon. Agradeço novamente. A principio, em tua opiniao, o subMonth() funcionando somente subtraindo o mes. Seria uma funcionalidade mal feita ou deveria funcionar assim mesmo?

Comment: Na verdade o Carbon é dependente do `DateTime` do PHP, então esse comportamento é do próprio `DateTime`. Acredito que isso acontece por questão de perfomance, pois é mais fácil subtrair somente o mês ao invés de validar a data. Mas também o  `DateTime` oferece outras formas de buscar determinadas datas como o @AndersonCarlosWoss mostrou.

Answer (score 4):

Acontece uma incoerência do dia do mês. Estamos em 31/07, quando você faz `Carbon::now()->subMonth()` ele basicamente irá subtrair um mês da data, obtendo 31/06. Como o mês de Junho não possui o dia 31, ele muda para 01/07, que é o dia seguinte. Se mudasse para 30/06 a diferença entre as datas seria maior que um mês.

Veja isso com a classe `DateTime`:

```php
$now = new DateTime("2019-07-31");
$now->modify("-1 month");

var_dump($now);
```

A saída será:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-07-01 17:50:54.359727"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Veja que ele mudou para 01/07. Esse comportamento não aconteceria, por exemplo, se estivéssemos em Agosto, que também tem 31 dias:

```php
$now = new DateTime("2019-08-31");
$now->modify("-1 month");

var_dump($now);
```

Obtendo a saída esperada 31/07, pois Julho possui o dia 31.

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-07-31 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Para obter as datas que você deseja, com `DateTime`, você poderia fazer:

```php
$inicioMesAtual = new DateTime("first day of this month");  // 2019-07-01
$fimMesAtual =  new DateTime("last day of this month");  // 2019-07-31

$inicioMesPassado = new DateTime("first day of last month");  // 2019-06-01
$fimMesPassado = new DateTime("last day of last month");  // 2019-06-31
```

Como a classe `Carbon` herda de `DateTime`, basta fazer:

```php
$inicioMesAtual = new Carbon("first day of this month");  // 2019-07-01
$fimMesAtual =  new Carbon("last day of this month");  // 2019-07-31

$inicioMesPassado = new Carbon("first day of last month");  // 2019-06-01
$fimMesPassado = new Carbon("last day of last month");  // 2019-06-31
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, agradeço pela resposta. Eu fui pesquisar no github e apareceu alguma coisa assim, como dica pra ajustar, usando o proprio PHP em vez do Carbon. A principio, tu consideraria o subMonth() do Carbon como algo não recomendavel para uso?

Comment: Não sei dizer se é ou não recomendado, pois nunca usei o Carbon (nunca vi sentido nele), mas podemos dizer que é desnecessário nesse problema. Não vejo justificativa em executar operações aritméticas entre datas para obter algo que pode ser obtido de uma forma mais simples.